# 一つのネットワークに複数デバイスがつながっているのに、自分とルーターしか検出できない

Tags: ios, macos, network

### 困っていること

同じネットワークに繋がってるはずなのに、自分とルーター以外のデバイスを検出できず困っています。

### 説明

家でBuffaloのWHR-G301Nというルーターを使っています。
MacでLanScanというアプリやiPhoneでFingというアプリを使うと、
自分がつながってるネットワークにつながってるデバイス一覧を見ることができます。

ところが、それらのアプリで確認しても、
自分とルーターしかリストに出てきません。

例
A端末でサーチ:A端末とルーターのみ検出できる
B端末でサーチ:B端末とルーターのみ検出できる
※前提として、A端末もB端末も同じネットワークにつながっている。
-> 同じネットワークにつながってるのに、自分とルーターしか検出できてないということ

### 質問

何かネットワークの設定がいけないとかなのでしょうか?
わかる方がいらっしゃれば教えていただきたいです。

### この問題のために今はこう回避している

この問題のために、スマホ実機からMac内のローカルのWEBサイトやAPIにアクセスするときに、
毎回スマホをテザリングして、それにPCをぶらさげて、確認をするというめんどくさいことをしています。
(この方法だと、MacでifconfigしたIPを指定するとアクセスすることが出来る)

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ルーターがブロックしてるんでは？と予測しますがそのルーターのことは分からないのでなんともいえませんね。iPhoneのIPアドレスを確認してMacからPingすると応答ありますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。pingすると、Request timeoutになり、届かないです。ルーターが192.168.11.1でなぜか192.168.11.2はpingがとおります。それ以降は通らないです。192.168.11.2はなんなのかはちょっとわからないです

Answer (score 1):

無線接続の機器同士の通信を禁止する**プライバシーセパレーター**が有効になっていませんでしょうか？下記設定ガイドを参考に、WHR-G301Nを確認してみてください。もし、有効になっている場合は、無効にして試してみてください。

[エアステーション設定ガイド(31版) - 無線パソコン同士の通信を禁止する（プライバシーセパレーター）](http://buffalo.jp/download/manual/html/air1300/)